# Git merge failed to bring over some files

Tags: git

I did a large merge from `develop` to `master` and Git handled it mostly correctly. But there were three files that definitely existed in both branches prior to the merge but Git only recognized the old ones in master, as they were all marked as `added by us`. I expected instead to get a conflict I could resolve, because I wanted the changes that exist in `develop`. The only thing it would let me do to resolve it was either add them (meaning I'd be keeping the old `master` version or remove them. I choose the latter and attempted another merge, but it says I'm already up-to-date. Now the files exist in `develop` but not in `master`, but Git seems to have no clue about this. Why won't Git let me bring these files over and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: you can use "gitk --all" to check if every checkin works all right. DO remember every branch is clean before u do the merge

Answer (score 1):

So there are 3 files in `develop` that you want in `master`. Try this

```
git checkout master  # make sure you are on the master branch 
git checkout develop -- name_of_file_1.ext name_of_file_2.ext name_of_file_3.ext
```

This should bring over the 3 files you want from `develop` in their most recent state.

Comment: That actually copies files from master to develop.